# How to support Loop in a webtest uploaded to application insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

In my webtest, I am trying to poll some backend operation status in a loop until the status reaches a final one: complete/fail. But seems the application insights does not support loop operation in a webtest.

```
Visual studio web test(id = 'CaseName') contains a loop. Loops are not supported.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Application Insights doesn't support loops.

Comment: One option - if it is okay to wait for some time (note, built-in sleep is disabled as well) - web test can ping some web site which does the sleep. Some customers do it. Note #2 - there is a limit of 2 minutes for overall web test execution

Comment: Another option - setup Azure Function which does what's needed and then use web test just to trigger it and convert to Availability data in Application Insights (so, it is possible to alert/etc.)

Comment: thanks! Instead of ping a 'sleep website', is it possible to implement a request plugin by which we could do the 'Thread.sleep' in its Pre/PostRequest? I found it is doable from visual studio but I did not find a way to upload the plugin dll to application insights.

Comment: With Performance Web Tests being deprecated starting Visual Studio 2021 (Application Insights will run them at least for a year after its own announcement, there are no plans to announce it for upcoming year; So, life of these tests is projected to be at least two years. Single Url tests are not affected), I doubt that we will be able to support this.